# escaping characters trying to assemble literal strings is putting double slashes in my string, how do I escape using a single slash?

Tags: ruby, string, escaping, literals

I'm trying to put together some dynamic regex. For my test case I'm trying to put together the string "/[^\%|\!]*/" from an array of the pseudo-escape characters markers = ["%", "!"].

The problem is from escaping the characters when concatenating the escape characters to the characters in the array:

```
markers.map {|a| "\\#{a}"} 
  => ["\\%", "\\!"]
markers.map {|a| '\' + a}  
  => expects another line because it's only escaping the single quote to literal, and not closing the first chunk
markers.map {|a| '\\' + a} 
  => ["\\%", "\\!"]
```

The closest I've gotten is attempt 3 from above. I can get the correct strings with puts, but when I try and assemble the regex, it comes in with the double slashes and won't match what I'm looking for:

```
regex = "/[^#{markers.map {|a| '\\' + a}.join('|')}]*/"
  => "/[^\\%|\\!]*/"
```

How do I apply the escape character for use in a regular expression to the markers in an array when concatenating strings like this? Or, if there's a better way to go about this, what is it?

Comment: A single slash in a Ruby string is represented by two slashes. Two slashes become four slashes. And so on. The extra slashes are just a visual. If your regex doesn't work as expected the issue is elsewhere. How do you convert the string into a regex?

Comment: @cremno, I convert the array exactly the way I show in the example, except I'm trying to map! in the escape characters to the array first because I can't figure out a way to .join them that incorporates the escape character.

Answer (score 0):

I actually found a way around it, but no proper explanation. You need to have the mapping occur with double quotes inside the .map as you generate the regex object:

```
regex = %r{[^#{markers.map {|a| "\\"+ a}.join('|').to_s}]*}
=> /[^\%|\!]*/
```